# Django filter with OR statement

Tags: python, django

I need to write filter that will check situation like:

if there are an actors with name "John" than return these actors, otherwise search actors with name "David".

Pseudocode may look like:

```
Actors.filter(name="John" or name="David")
```

Can i do something like this in Django using one query? or do I have to use `if` ?

```
actors = Actor.filter(name="John")
if not actors.exists():
    actors = Actors.filter(name="David")
```

Comment: An OR query wouldn't give you the result you want; it would give you all actors whose name is either John or David, ie a mix of both. If you only want Davids if there are no Johns, your second example is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Q` objects. Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q)
provides a more detailed description about the `Q` objects. In short, it allows you to do more complex queries like `AND`, `OR` queries. 
For your question specifically you can do like this:

```
Actor.objects.filter(Q(name="John") | Q(name="David"))
```

And in general here are some cool stuffs you can do with `Q` objects.

You can use `Q` to create dynamic query also. For example:

```
    import operator
    try:
        from functools import reduce
    except ImportError:  # Python < 3
        pass

    q_list = [Q(question__contains='dinner'), Q(question__contains='meal')]
    Poll.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, q_list))
```

the example in this post is taken from [this post.](http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2010/07/20/the-power-of-djangos-q-objects/)